# Scope on ASP .NET Core entity framework

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to use scope (like scope on rails, below) on .NET core.

```
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```

Does .NET Core have scopes like rails?
Or what is best practice to default query on netcore model, like scope on rails?

Comment: Maybe you should start by explaining what **scope** means in context of ruby on rails first

Comment: thanks, but in the end, i using soft deleted on net core, because on the first, my purpose to exclude row with delete state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use EF Core's [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to achieve this.

From the doc examples:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

To disable it on a single query, use `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` Linq extension method.

```
blogs = db.Blogs
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually, this is more like [default_scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class) than a regular [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope). By the way, for me looks "out of place" to put your where conditions in the dbContext and not in the model itself.